# Creating QR Code in Indesign

Tags: qr-code, adobe-indesign

I'm using Adobe Creative Suite.   I have a subscription so I have the most current version of the software.  I have never used InDesign before (Never needed to, until now).

I've looked online and found how to create a QR Code in Indesign.  However, the QR code is so thick!  When I look at the examples on youtube, or adobe help, I follow the instructions.  The tutorials show nicely proportioned qr codes.  I have searched for answers on why mine is so thick (I have checked stroke and fill and stroke is 0 and there is no fill.)

No idea why this is happening or how to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated!

PS:  My monitor is 1920x1080.[image]

Comment: This is not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change View > Display Performance to "High Quality Display."

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  The reason the QR code looked so messy is because InDesign allows a content creator to use less processing power by lowering the display performance.

You can adjust the display performance by going to: View -> Display Performance -> choose "Fast", "Typical" or "High".

The default is "Typical" which makes the QR code look a little wonky.

Cheers to myself!

Comment: Thanks user1754036, I actually didn't see your answer until I answered my own question.  However, I added a point to your answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While it may look wonky and chunky on your display, the output is still perfect. I just had this issue (before finding this thread) and the QR codes in the output PDF files are totally fine and proportional.